# How can I optimize global language array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a language file which holds one array `$phrases` of around 3k lines.

```
$phrases = array();
$phrases['hello'] = 'bonjour';
```

I created a function to retrieve values from this array.

```
function phrase($identifier) {
   global $phrases;
   return $phrases['identifier'];
}
```

Which I use as follows:

```
function some_view() {
   $intro = phrase('hello') . $firstname;
}
```

How can I optimize this code to guarantee performance as the language file grows over time?

Comment: what is your worry? Array access in PHP is O(1).

Comment: What exactly is what you want to optimize? Lookup is always going to be fast, no matter the size. If you want to optimize for memory you may want to break apart your array in different "domains", so you don't load thousands of unneeded strings. Bit by bit you'll end up more or less reimplementing `gettext` and family. ;)

Comment: SPLFixedArray comes to mind

Comment: @yivi Good point about gettext(), looking into it.

Comment: @hanshenrik Not sure how SPLFixedArray can help, its keys are integers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The penalty you will pay for this large array of language lines is probably going to be assessed at compile/run time, not during the language string lookup operations. If you want to optimize it, I suggest you break up your language strings into smaller sections or something and load each section only as needed.

I did some testing. Just assigning values to an array doesn't take much time. This function generates random $key values and assigns an associative array $key => $key some number of times.

```
function get_str() {
    $retval = "";
    for($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
            $retval .= chr(mt_rand(ord("A"), ord("Z")));
    }
    return $retval;
}

$arr = array();
$el1 = 0;
for($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) {
    $key = get_str();
    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $arr[$key] = $key;
    $el1 += (microtime(TRUE) - $start);
}
var_dump($el1);
```

The results:

```
10 elements         1.1920928955078E-5
100 elements        9.4175338745117E-5
1,000 elements      0.00090622901916504 // less than a millisecond
1,000,000 elements  1.0554702281952
```

this is not a very heavy penalty.  I added some code to perform 1,000 lookups:

```
$el2 = 0;
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $lookup = get_str();
    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $val = (isset($arr[$lookup]) ? $arr[$lookup] : "");
    $el2 += (microtime(TRUE) - $start);
}
var_dump($el2);
```

I varied the number of elements in the array from 10 to 1,000,000 and performed 1,000 lookups on each array size. The results:

```
10 elements         0.00072717666625977
100 elements        0.00070691108703613
1000 elements       0.00071167945861816 // less than a millisecond
1,000,000 elements  0.0008540153503418 // still less than a millisecond
```

As you can see, associative hash lookups stay efficient, even for very large data structures

Comment: Wow, awesome reply!

Comment: It kinda is the solution, it shows that there are no performance issues with my suggested code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Localization using arrays is easy and fast, but it lacks some functionalities you might want in the future (like dealing with date formats, currencies or plurals, for instance).

Here's an [article](https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/php-how-to-translate-php-apps/) that explains very well the possibilities you have and you can think which one adapts to your project better.

Personally, if the project is big enough, I always stick with the Translator component of Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html